# Installiing XV on windows using cygwin

Tags: x11, cygwin, image-viewer

I am using cygwin on Windows 10. I can't seem to find any package named xv while in the cygwin setup. How can I use xv on Windows using cygwin or otherwise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not [unix.se] specific, it would better fit at [su].

Comment: Cygwin is Unix, Gnu is Unix, UNIX is Unix, BSD is Unix, Linux is a kernel. Cygwin is a dll that emulates a Posix/Unix kernel. It is used to create a Gnu environment on Microsoft's Windows (we also have a tag for it).

Comment: Try [cygwin ports](https://sourceforge.net/p/cygwin-ports/xv/ci/master/tree/).

Comment: Per https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/cygwin-on-topic this seems on-topic here (especially if the answer involves compiling it, just like you would on a real Unix)

Comment: @ridgy That'd make for the start of a good answer. Please consider posting it as an answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: How about using another image viewer? One of the many that have been maintained in the past two decades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As XV is not provided you can try to compile it by yourself.

However as the code is a bit old, last version in 1994, 
there is no guarantee that it will easily build in modern 
systems like current Cygwin
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xv_%28software%29

As there are several equivalent programs in cygwin, you can try one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed XV on an older version of Cygwin-X like 5 years ago and xv would not come up on the startx windows. I would have to run the rxvt-native, and only then it would come up. 
On a newer computer with Windows 10, I installed Cygwin-X, but the rxvt-native is not available anymore (or not yet?) in the latest version of Cygwin-X. I wasn't able to have xv windows open up. So it seems, for now, xv can't work on Cygwin-X, at least not as it is.
XV can still be obtained from John Bradley (just google xv john bradley) for a little fee
and it will work on other unix-like OS, maybe with some tweaking because, as it has been mentioned, the software was written 24 years ago.

Comment: Please provide reference